# Instant Payment Notification (IPN) returning Html

Tags: paypal-ipn

We are requesting the following URL "https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb" with `cmd=_notify-validate` to get the notification of `VERIFIED` or `INVALID` as per the documentation (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside), but we are receiving a completely different response. This causes problems because as a result our system doesn't behave as expected.

Response:

> Error Processing Payment Error Message "This transaction can't be
>   processed. Please pay with another card."

Please help me why I am facing this issue however we are receiving payment successfully and everything was working fine a couple of days ago.

Comment: could you add a few details in what you tried before? May it be related with some additional steps that have to be executed beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and to make it clear, **https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr** URL is for IPNs and **https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb** is for receiving payments through hosted sole solution(developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#HSS).

May be PayPal has changed something in their API.

Comment: Nope. You used the wrong URL. I've been using the webscr one since 2009 or so, as per the IPN documentation, The URL you used isn't in there.